# Como gravar uma imagem base64_encode com mais de 4000 caracteres no Oracle usando php

Tags: php, imagem, oracle, base64

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem base64_encode com php no Oracle, porém no momento do insert ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

**ORA-01704: literal de string extenso demais.**

O motivo de retornar esse erro é porque a string é muito grande, eu queria saber se tem algum método ou função do Oracle que ajuda nessa situação, por exemplo algum tipo de conversão ou coisa parecida.

Comment: Primeiramente, **não recomendo inserir esse tipo de conteúdo no banco**.
Por segundo, qual o tipo do campo que você esta usando para inserir?

Comment: Estou usando blob

Comment: E qual o tamanho defino para ele? [blob](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefblob.html)

Comment: Não defini o tamanho na hora da criação, pode ser esse o problema, sabe como seria para definir o tamanho de um campo blob?

Comment: "A BLOB without a specified length is defaulted to two gigabytes (2,147,483,647)."
Um BLOB sem comprimento especificado é definido com padrão de 2GB (2,147,483,647).

Comment: Contudo, note que estamos falando de tamanho em bytes, na documentação diz que estas seria um informação complementar, você não definiu ele com algum tipo `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `CHAR`?

Comment: não não, já tentei como blob e clob.